# Slither cannot find the dependency with @openzeppelin

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, openzeppelin

```
Error: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
```

Currently, all dependencies from `@openzeppelin` are showing errors like this. But those dependencies have been installed in my `node_modules` and I don't know why it can't find the file. Is there a way I can set the location, or should I install the `@openzeppelin/contracts` globally?

UPDATE：I can see that `--base-path` should be set for `solc`, but I am still not sure how to apply such setting to `slither`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a (might be dirty) way to solve it:

Step 1: Go to the directory where all your dependencies are.

In my case, do `cd node_modules`

Step 2: Call the same command with the updated relative path.

In my case, from `slither contracts/MyContract.sol` to `slither ../contracts/MyContract.sol`

And it just works. After going through the doc, I don't think Slither is providing a way to adjust `--base-path` as a flag.

Comment: yep, this worked for me as well. In case if anyone is wondering about "node_modules" folder. Its the place were Dependencies mentioned in package.json file is saved. For example openzeppelin and appropriate version will be defined in package.json. 
So For executing above method, if folder "node_modules" is missing for you. Navigate to folder where your package.json is present and execute `npm i --save` to create "node_modules" folder